# addSubview in UIViewController's View has no response

Tags: ios4, uiview, uiviewcontroller

Newbie question. I created a UIView named `TestView` with 2 IBOutlet UIButton. I would like to add this view to initially launched view controller.

The header file of the TestView is as follow:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface TestView : UIView {
    IBOutlet UIButton *btn1;
    IBOutlet UIButton *btn2;
}

@end
```

I try to add the view to the screen by:

```
TestView *view = [[TestView alloc] init];
[self.view addSubview:view];
[view release];
```

but I got no response. How can I add TestView to the original view ?

p.s. TestView as a XIB too, named TestView.xib

Environment:

- xCode 4
- iOS 4.3.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

u have to specify the frame

frame means orgin + size

here orgin (0,0)

size (200,200)

otherwise iOs dont know where to draw this view

```
TestView *view = [[TestView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460)];

[view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]]; 

[view addSubview:btn1];

[view addSubview:btn2];
//here add whatever u want

[self.view addSubview:view];

[view release];
```

Comment: interesting. your answer is very close. when I execute your codes, green color appears, but not the contents in XIB. Did I miss something ?

Comment: but y do u do like this.just drag the view from IB then add btns.simple

Comment: I have made the layout in IB. But how can I load it out ?

Comment: dont worry friend here is ur step step visual tutorial. http://adeem.me/blog/2009/07/03/beignner-iphone-sdk-hello-world-tutorial-first-application/

Comment: Thanks for tutorial. Can I make like this : 1 ViewController XIB with multiple views in it, each assigned to IBOutlet. When switching back & forth between screens, I will just need to show & hide the views. But will this method use a lot of memory? Actually I have an alternate solution, which uses UIViewController presentModalViewController:animated method. It works perfectly, but I would like to keep the background not moving away.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't call it view because your UIView's got already an instance variable called view.

You could also create this using Interface Builder and linking your elements to your Outlets, it will be easier

Comment: scope of this 2 view variable is different . self.view is not equal to view . It's okay to name it like this .

Comment: you're absolutely right. Worst that could happen is you get a warning I guess